# Ranking on same data in SQL Lite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have table as below

```
CREATE TABLE test(
   ID INT
);
```

With Following data

[image: Sample Data]

I need following result

```
ID    Rank
100   1
100   2
105   1
105   2
105   3
```

I only need to use normal SQL Query no special functions

Comment: Why no special functions?

Comment: I can only functions which are supported in SQL Lite

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`rowid`](http://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid) in a correlated query to achieve the result. Since, rowid uniquely identifies as row, we can use it in our case to do correlated counting to assign row number.

Try this:

```
select id, (
        select count(*)
        from test t2
        where t.id = t2.id
            and t2.rowid <= t.rowid
        ) rank
from test t;
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer?